# MobileFirst Console - Wlapp Upload Fails After 60 seconds

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty, mobilefirst-server

I have already installed & configured following items :

- Installed IBM WebSphere Application Server Liberty Core (Version 8.5.5)
- Installed IBM MobileFirst Platform Server (Verison 7.1)

While uploading wlapp file to mobilefirst console, If it takes longer than 60 seconds, then it throws an error :

> Connection failure. Check server log for details.

Here is my server.xml :

```
<server description="new server">
    <featureManager>
        <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
        <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
        <feature>servlet-3.0</feature>
        <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>restConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>appSecurity-1.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <httpSession cloneId="server1" />
    <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                  host="*"
                  httpPort="9080"
                  httpsPort="9443" >

        <tcpOptions  inactivityTimeout="10m" soReuseAddr="true"/>
        <httpOptions readTimeout="10m" writeTimeout="10m" removeServerHeader="true" />
    </httpEndpoint>

    <administrator-role>
        <user>WorklightRESTUser</user>
    </administrator-role>

    <basicRegistry>
        <user name="WorklightRESTUser" password="yfcXTcXUEcTV"/>
        <user name="admin" password="admin"/>
    </basicRegistry>

    <webContainer invokeFlushAfterService="false" deferServletLoad="false"/>

    <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.endpoint" value="http://IP:PORT/wladmin" />
    <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.proxy.protocol" value="http" />
    <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.proxy.host" value="<IP>" />
    <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.proxy.port" value="<PORT>"/>

    <application id="HelloWorld" name="HelloWorld" location="HelloWorld.war" type="war">
        <classloader delegation="parentLast">
            <privateLibrary id="worklightlib_HelloWorld">
                <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/HelloWorld/lib" includes="worklight-jee-library.jar"/>
                <fileset dir="${wlp.install.dir}/lib" includes="com.ibm.ws.crypto.passwordutil_*.jar"/>
            </privateLibrary>
        </classloader>
    </application>

    <jndiEntry jndiName="HelloWorld/publicWorkLightProtocol" value='"http"'/>
    <jndiEntry jndiName="HelloWorld/publicWorkLightPort" value='"9080"'/>
    <jndiEntry jndiName="HelloWorld/reports.exportRawData" value='"false"'/>

    <library id="HelloWorld/DB2Lib">
        <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/HelloWorld/db2" includes="db2jcc4.jar"/>
    </library>

    <dataSource jndiName="HelloWorld/jdbc/WorklightDS" transactional="false">
        <jdbcDriver libraryRef="HelloWorld/DB2Lib"/>
        <properties.db2.jcc databaseName="MF_HELLO" serverName="<IP>" portNumber="<PORT>" user="<USER>" password="<PWD>" currentSchema="WRKLGHT"/>
    </dataSource>

    <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="worklight"/>

    <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.host" value='"localhost"'/>
    <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.port" value='"9443"'/>
    <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.user" value='"WorklightRESTUser"'/>
    <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.pwd" value='"yfcXTcXUEcTV"'/>
    <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.topology.platform" value='"Liberty"'/>
    <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.topology.clustermode" value='"Standalone"'/>

    <executor id="default" name="LargeThreadPool"
              coreThreads="200" maxThreads="400" keepAlive="60s"
              stealPolicy="STRICT" rejectedWorkPolicy="CALLER_RUNS"/>

    <application id="wladmin" name="wladmin" location="worklightadmin.war" type="war">
        <application-bnd>
            <security-role name="worklightadmin">
                <user name="admin"/>
            </security-role>
            <security-role name="worklightdeployer">
            </security-role>
            <security-role name="worklightmonitor">
            </security-role>
            <security-role name="worklightoperator">
            </security-role>
        </application-bnd>

        <classloader delegation="parentLast">
            <commonLibrary id="worklightlib_wladmin">
                <fileset dir="${wlp.install.dir}/lib" includes="com.ibm.ws.crypto.passwordutil_*.jar"/>
            </commonLibrary>
        </classloader>
    </application>

    <library id="wladmin/DB2Lib">
        <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/wladmin/db2" includes="db2jcc4.jar"/>
    </library>

    <dataSource jndiName="wladmin/jdbc/WorklightAdminDS" transactional="false">
        <jdbcDriver libraryRef="wladmin/DB2Lib"/>
        <properties.db2.jcc databaseName="WRKLGHT" serverName="IP" portNumber="PORT" user="USER" password="PWD" currentSchema="WLADMIN"/>
    </dataSource>

    <application id="worklightconsole" name="worklightconsole" location="worklightconsole.war" type="war">
        <application-bnd>
            <security-role name="worklightadmin">
                <user name="admin"/>
            </security-role>
            <security-role name="worklightdeployer">
            </security-role>
            <security-role name="worklightmonitor">
            </security-role>
            <security-role name="worklightoperator">
            </security-role>
        </application-bnd>
        <classloader delegation="parentLast"/>
    </application>

    <jndiEntry jndiName="worklightconsole/ibm.worklight.admin.endpoint" value='"*://*:*/wladmin"'/>

</server>
```

In messages.log of server, I am getting this error :

> com.ibm.worklight.management.ui.servlet.ServiceProxy
>   Throwable Connection closed: Read failed.  Possible end of stream
>   encountered.  while redirecting request to
>   http://localhost:9080/wladmin/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/HelloWorld/applications?async=true

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the structure of your network topology? 1 server? a farm of servers? load balancer? http server?

Comment: There is only one WAS server and I am accessing it directly, there is not any http server in between.

Comment: Provide the full messages.log file.

Comment: What are PORT and IP in :

    <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.endpoint" value="http://IP:PORT/wladmin" />
    <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.proxy.protocol" value="http" />
    <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.proxy.host" value="<IP>" />
    <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.proxy.port" value="<PORT>"/>

Comment: @IdanAdar : This is the full messages.log file : http://tinyurl.com/o9cjuoj

Comment: @BrunoCharpentier : IP is 192.168.10.177 and port is 9080.
Sorry for not mentioning it before.

Comment: Set the following trace in server.xml :  <logging traceSpecification="com.ibm.worklight.*=all:com.worklight.*=all" traceFileName="trace.log" maxFileSize="20" maxFiles="10" traceFormat="BASIC"></logging>, stop the server, clean the logs directory, restart the server, test and attach the trace.log file

Comment: @BrunoCharpentier : I put the logging entry in server.xml and then restarted the server, here is the trace file : http://tinyurl.com/pcvaou5

Comment: @IdanAdar : Issue still persists. Did you check the log file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixes published later than 2016-03-23 should fix the problem.
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI59605

Answer (score 0):

Your Liberty Profile version is 8.5.5.0. This version is not supported. Minimal version is 8.5.5.3 (see http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/prereqsForProduct?deliverableId=46183B706BEA11E48038141DE954FC88, tab Supported Software). It can explain this kind of problem because this Liberty version has defects concerning jndi management, REST connection..

Comment: Thank you for your response. Let suppose WAS Liberty 8.5.5.0 has defects concerning jndi management, REST connection, but while uploading wlapp why it always throws error after 60 seconds? Don't you think It's something related to timeout?

Comment: I installed liberty profile version 8.5.5.5. Still the same issue persists. All error logs are same as before.

Comment: I'm using 8.5.5.5 as well.... facing the same issue... Was able to upload smaller app size about 20MB. Having issues with 60MB+ files.